# always calling the service API when resetting the form control in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, valuechangelistener

I have a component below that basically calls an external API service within `ngOnInit` - this returns an array of gifs in `this.items`.

I have the function `applyGif` - once a user clicks an image it calls this function and resets the Form `searchTerm` the problem is each time I call `resetSearchBox` to clear the text input box it runs the `valueChanges` event and executes the the `gifpickerService.search` again with a string value of 'null' - I do not want it to ever call this if it has no value - what am I doing wrong?

I want to reset the form but not call the `search()` within the `ngOnInit` - what am doing wrong?

```
export class GifpickerComponent implements OnInit {
   public searchTerm : FormControl = new FormControl();
   public items: any = [];

   @Output() gifSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

   constructor(private gifpickerService: GifpickerService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       this.searchTerm.valueChanges
          .debounceTime(1000)
          .subscribe(data => {
             this.gifpickerService.search(data).subscribe(response =>{
                 this.items = response;
           })

      })
   }

  applyGif(gif): any {
      let gifMedia = gif.media[0];
      this.gifSelected.emit(gifMedia);
      this.resetSearchBox();
  }

  toggleGifList(): void {
      this.items = [];
  }

  resetSearchBox(): void {
      this.searchTerm.reset();
  }
}
```

/* html component */

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item" class="gif-list-item">
      <img [src]="item.media[0].tinygif.url" (click)="applyGif(item)" />
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: check if data is 'undefined' in your subscribe to 'searchTerm.valueChanges'

Comment: In your valueChanges OUTER subscribe, just check for the new value of searchterm (Data). If empty do not execute the this.gifpickerService.search(data).subscribe

Comment: add a condition to check if `data` is not null in `valueChanges` subscribe callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are resetting the form control, the value changes and thus triggers the `valueChanges`. You can use `emitEvent: false` which means it will not trigger `valueChanges`:

```
resetSearchBox(): void {
  this.searchTerm.reset(null, { emitEvent: false });
}
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :)